# Check if two unordered lists are equal with certain conditions

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for an easy (and quick) way to determine if two unordered lists contain the same elements(explained in below example):

```
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'two', 'three'] :  true
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'three', 'two'] :  true
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'] :  false
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'three', 'four','five'] :  false
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'two'] :  true
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one'] :  true
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your example you need to check if the second list is a subset of the first list. You can do this using `issubset`:

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'three']
b = ['one']

print(set(b).issubset(a))
```